# How do I get this CSS text-decoration override to work?

Tags: html, css, text-decorations

Some days I swear I'm going mad. This is one of those days. I thought my CSS was fairly straight-forward here, but it just doesn't seem to be working. What am I missing?

My CSS looks like this:

```
ul > li {
    text-decoration: none;
}
ul > li.u {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
ul > li > ul > li {
    text-decoration: none;
}
ul > li > ul > li.u {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

And my HTML looks like this:

```html
<ul>
  <li>Should not be underlined</li>
  <li class="u">Should be underlined
    <ul>
      <li>Should not be underlined</li>
      <li class="u">Should be underlined</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Yet it comes up like this:

[image]

Comment: In XHTML, yes it has been deprecated.

Comment: Applying a border to the bottom should give a nice alternative to using underline.  Some argue that it looks better and you can tweak spacing with padding.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

`text-decoration` does not behave the same as other font/text related styling like `font-weight`. Applying `text-decoration` will affect all nested elements as well.

Check this out:
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#propdef-text-decoration

Excerpt:

> Text decorations on inline boxes are
>   drawn across the entire element, going
>   across any descendant elements without
>   paying any attention to their
>   presence. The 'text-decoration'
>   property on descendant elements cannot
>   have any effect on the decoration of
>   the element
>   . . . .
>   Some user agents
>   have implemented text-decoration by
>   propagating the decoration to the
>   descendant elements as opposed to
>   simply drawing the decoration through
>   the elements as described above. This
>   was arguably allowed by the looser
>   wording in CSS2.

I've got the info from: http://csscreator.com/node/14951

Comment: So essentially it can't be done; instead I'll have to make sure never to set that property on a parent li, and instead include a <span> there or somesuch. It seems like a stupid and arbitrary rule to include in the CSS spec; it's so counter-intuitive.

Comment: Sadly speaking, that is true. To be honest, if not for your question, I wouldn't have found that out as well :P

Comment: @o.k.w , I just faced the same problem, but I guess you can still apply text-decorations on nested elements by converting them to block elements. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10478919/css-line-through-is-not-disabled-on-nested-span/10478962#comment13540343_10478962

Comment: Saw this solution on another question, use `display: inline-block;` to clear out the item's `text-decoration`. http://stackoverflow.com/a/19529256/1977420

Comment: This answer is outdated; Oriol’s answer shows how to override the underlining for inner elements.

Answer (score 35):

You get rid of `text-decoration` applied to a parent element in those cases:

- [Out-of-flow](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#x23) elements, such as floated and absolutely positioned ones

  ```css
  li {
    float: left; /* Avoid text-decoration propagation from ul */
    clear: both; /* One li per line */
  }
  ul { overflow: hidden; } /* Clearfix */
  ```

  ```css
  ul {
    overflow: hidden; /* Clearfix */
  }
  li {
    float: left; /* Avoid text-decoration propagation from ul */
    clear: both; /* One li per line */
  }
  li.u {
    text-decoration: underline;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <ul>
    <li>Should not be underlined</li>
    <li class="u">Should be underlined
      <ul>
        <li>Should not be underlined</li>
        <li class="u">Should be underlined</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  ```
- [Atomic inline-level](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#x13) elements, such as inline blocks and inline tables

  But if you use `li{display:inline-block}`, then you don't have bullets (you lose `display:list-item`) and the items appear one next to the others.

  Then, to have one item per line, you can use

  ```css
  li {
    display: inline-block; /* Avoid text-decoration propagation from ul */
    width: 100%;           /* One li per line */
  }
  ```

  And to add the bullets, you can use `::before` pseudo-elements. However, bullets shouldn't be underlined, so you will need to take them out-of-flow or make them atomic inline-level too.

  ```css
  li {
    display: inline-block; /* Avoid text-decoration propagation from ul */
    width: 100%;           /* One li per line */
  }
  li:before {
    content: '• ';         /* Insert bullet */
    display: inline-block; /* Avoid text-decoration propagation from li */
    white-space: pre-wrap; /* Don't collapse the whitespace */
  }
  li.u {
    text-decoration: underline;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <ul>
    <li>Should not be underlined</li>
    <li class="u">Should be underlined
      <ul>
        <li>Should not be underlined</li>
        <li class="u">Should be underlined</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  ```

  ```css
  li {
    display: inline-block; /* Avoid text-decoration propagation from ul */
    width: 100%;           /* One li per line */
  }
  li:before {
    content: '•';          /* Insert bullet */
    position: absolute;    /* Avoid text-decoration propagation from li */
    margin-left: -.75em;
  }
  li.u {
    text-decoration: underline;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <ul>
    <li>Should not be underlined</li>
    <li class="u">Should be underlined
      <ul>
        <li>Should not be underlined</li>
        <li class="u">Should be underlined</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  ```

---

This behavior is specified in [CSS 2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#lining-striking-props) and [CSS Text Decoration Module Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-decor-3/#line-decoration):

> Note that text decorations are not propagated to any out-of-flow
>   descendants, nor to the contents of atomic inline-level descendants
>   such as inline blocks and inline tables.

Comment: you can use `inline:block` on a div inside the `li` so you don't loose the bullets

Answer (score 2):

The reason you´re seeing what you're seeing is that your rule

```
ul > li.u
```

takes preference over:

```
ul > li > ul > li
```

as a class is specified and that has more weight than the element selectors together.

**Edit:** What you could try is:

```
.u ul {
        text-decoration: none;
}
.u {
        text-decoration: underline;
}
```

and play around with that (perhaps you will have to use **li.u** instead of just **.u**).

**However**, depending on the content you might want to wrap the underlined parts in **q**, **em** or **strong** tags and style these tags instead of using a class. That way you would be describing your content as well as styling it.

Comment: This is correct, the most specific rule in css will have the most weight in the cascading appliance of those rules, #id is most specific, then .class, then element selectors.

Comment: I saw a list somewhere once with the exact values to calculate the weight of a rule. Can´t find it now though...

Comment: I understand, but fundamentally my question is how I go about overriding that underline property that's being inherited and setting it back to none, as it seems to be ignoring that currently, even if I add !important to the more specific none rule.

Answer (score 2):

[o.k.w.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823341/how-do-i-get-this-css-text-decoration-issue-to-work/1823388#1823388) above explains perfectly why you can't do what you are asking without some other changes. No, you're not going mad!

Possible workarounds:

- try `border-bottom`?
- wrap the text you want underlined in a `span class="u"` tag? (to prevent the text-decoration from decorating nested elements)
- if you aren't able to change the markup, you could add some scripting to accomplish the same as my previous suggestion.

Best of luck!

Comment: I often simplify/modify the examples that I give in questions to make my explanation as clear as possible. In reality, I'll actually be dealing with text-decoration: line-through, and none of the border properties really line up with that. It looks like either extra span tags or JavaScript is the solution. Both seem so inelegant though; this seems like this is a "bug" in the CSS spec more than anything.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue when using an external theme/CSS, so I couldn't modify it to remove the `text-decoration: none;`. In my case, I had a child element with a link, but the link wasn't being underlined as expected. I tried using `display: inline-block;` as others mentioned, but it has no effect.

What worked for me was overriding the `text-decoration` as you had done, but also including `!important` to force it to override the parent's `text-decoration`.

```
// Defined in an external CSS, so I couldn't modify it.
.footer {
    text-decoration: none;
}

// In my CSS file.
.footer a {
    text-decoration: underline !important;
}
```

So for your particular example, I imagine this may do the trick (I did not test it to confirm):

```
ul > li > ul > li {
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work. Could you upload a snippet at all?

Comment: @MathisHard I think the snippet I provided here is easier to understand, but [here's where I'm using it in my blog](https://github.com/deadlydog/deadlydog.github.io/blob/master/assets/css/main.scss#L241) if you want to see a real example in action.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest approach I’ve found is just to set the underline to the background’s colour.

Answer (score -3):

```
.u {text-decoration: underline;}
```

Comment: Doesn't work, since the child list will have all its elements underlined. See http://jsbin.com/iweri to see how this would look.

Comment: See Andrews code it's backwards of mine and it works. Weird that mine does not :)

Comment: OP already uses equivalent code, and there is no explanation. This is not an answer.