# Remove underline only from anchor element child

Tags: css

When an `a` tag contains child elements, like an `i` tag, it's still applying the underline to it on hover, and I'm wondering how to remove the underline from just the `i` tag when someone hovers over the `a` tag.

The CSS I'm working with:

```
a{
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
}
a i{
  color:#888;
  margin-left:5px;
}
a:hover{
    text-decoration:underline;
}
a:hover i{
    text-decoration:none !important;
}
```

Here is a fiddle to explain:
http://jsfiddle.net/kkz66x2q/

I simply would like the underline to be GONE only on the `i` element when you hover over the link.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get this CSS text-decoration override to work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823341/how-do-i-get-this-css-text-decoration-override-to-work) also this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3869286/any-way-to-stop-css-hover-text-decoration-underline-on-child

Comment: @web-tiki your example shows a nested group, my example shows a hover object. Please explain how they are similar. Thank you.

Comment: The `<i>` tag is nested in the `<a>` element therfore it is the same issue as in both links I provided. The fact that the underlining is set on over doesn't change the issue. + the solution provided in the answer below is already provided in the first link.

Comment: @web-tiki Explain how the answer from that question is the same as the answers given to this question

Comment: quote from the first link : "You can override text-decoration applied to a parent element with display:inline-block."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot undo text-decoration for child-elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434819/cannot-undo-text-decoration-for-child-elements)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Try following css,

```
a:hover i{
    display: inline-block; <-- this is the trick
    text-decoration:none !important;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kkz66x2q/4/)

Comment: I'm also curious as to why this works. Could anyone explain this?

Comment: Normally this would mean that you can only apply `text-decoration` to block level elements, but that isn't what's happening... so this doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: to explain this, it's specifically part of the CSS spec that inline blocks within a link don't get an underline.

you actually don't even need the `text-decoration:none !important;` line

Comment: @Chamika : I tried it in some html newsletters, and it's not working for some Outlook clients (Outlook 2013, 2010 for example). Any idea ?

Comment: What if the child element needs to be block level though?

Answer (score 4):

Set the `display` property of `i` to `inline-block`:

```
a i {
    ...
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kkz66x2q/3/)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and fixed this using the following css rule:

```
a:-webkit-any-link {text-decoration:none}
```

hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `display:inline-block;`

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kkz66x2q/6/)**

```
a:hover i {
    display:inline-block;
    text-decoration:none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also write you HTML like

```
    <a href="#">Link</a><i>(2)</i>
```

and CSS like

```
  a{
    display:inline-block;
    text-decoration:none;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

#### I got two things to add here…

using code sometimes as a child of an (regular inline) anchor, sometimes not:

```
  code
    font-family: Courier New, Courier, monospace
    color: green
    background: rgba( white, .2 )
    padding: 2px 4px
    text-decoration: none

  a code
    display: inline-block
    line-height: normal
    text-decoration: underline
```

1. You should add `line-height: normal` to kind of compensate for the inline-block, otherwise you will different paddings on linked elements than on others. (i.e. your line-height will easily start looking inconsistent)
2. And optionally: If you were just annoyed, that the underline has a *different* color (i.e. the [outer link color](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47928662/444255), rather than the green of `code`) settings text-decoration once *again* on that inner element helps…

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem.

But I wanted the inner element to be **Right**,
so setting just `float: right` worked fine.

```
a {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden; // Clearfix
    text-decoration: none;
}
a .right-none-underline-element { float: right }
```

For your reference.