# Unable to un-line-through a nested element

Tags: html, css

I want to apply a line-through to the contents of `<td>` tags except for the `<a>` tag within a  tag. The styles I am applying do not seem to work though... any ideas?

**Here's the example to play with (I'm testing in IE8):**
http://jsfiddle.net/9qbsq/

Here's what the markup looks like...

**HTML**

```
<table border=1>
  <tr class="highlight">
      <td>hello</td>
      <td><a href="#">world</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>foo</td>
      <td>bar</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
.highlight td { text-decoration:line-through; }
.highlight td a { text-decoration:none; }
```

Comment: You need to be clearer about how things "do not seem to work".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to wrap the text in something like a `span`, and apply `text-decoration: line-through` to that: http://jsfiddle.net/9qbsq/1/

That way, you don't have to achieve the impossible task of removing `line-through` on a child element when a parent element has `line-through` applied.

Comment: Good answer. The Sitepoint `text-decoration` [reference page](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/text-decoration) describes this behaviour: "Any text decoration setting on a descendant box can never 'undo' the text decorations of an ancestor box."

Comment: Better answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19529256/1977420. Change the item's display to `inline-block` to clear out its `text-decoration`.

Comment: Better in most cases, for sure. It does have the downside of having to set the element to inline-block which might be bad if you need text to wrap, here's a contrived example: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/9qbsq/19/

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that [`text-decoration`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#propdef-text-decoration) propagates to descendants:

> When specified on or propagated to an inline element, it affects all
>   the boxes generated by that element, and is further propagated to any
>   in-flow block-level boxes that split the inline [...]
>
> For block containers that establish an inline formatting context, the
>   decorations are propagated to an anonymous inline element that wraps
>   all the in-flow inline-level children of the block container.
>
> For all other elements it is propagated to any in-flow children.

But there are two exceptions: [out-of-flow](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#x23) and [atomic inline-level](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#x13) descendants:

> Note that text decorations are not propagated to floating and
>   absolutely positioned descendants, nor to the contents of atomic
>   inline-level descendants such as inline blocks and inline tables.

Therefore, you can use `display: inline-block` on a child to prevent its parent's `text-decoration` from affecting it.

```css
.highlight > td {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
.highlight > td > a {
  display: inline-block; /* Remove parent's text-decoration */
  text-decoration: none; /* Remove default link underline */
}
```

```html
<table border=1>
  <tr class="highlight">
    <td>hello</td>
    <td><a href="#">world</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>foo</td>
    <td>bar</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `text-decoration: none` is not necessery, because `display: inline-block` already removes it

Comment: @AlexanderMalakhov `display: inline-block` removes underline propagated from ancestor, but does not avoid self underline assigned in UA stylesheet.

Comment: This worked for me, but I couldn't use it on a `button` element. It did work when I targeted a `p` element inside the button. Does anyone know why that worked?

Answer (score 5):

That's how it should work - whilst the `a` element *does* have `text-decoration: none`, the line through is still being set.

You could add a span in each `td` as a workaround, and set the `text-decoration: line-through` on that `span` if required.

Comment: +1 Why this is the case, well, because the spec says so. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481318/css-text-decoration-property-cannot-be-overridden-by-ancestor-element/4481356#4481356).

Answer (score 2):

This issue can easily be solved with the :not attribute.

**HTML**

```
<table border=1>
  <tr class="highlight">
      <td>hello</td>
      <td class='nostrike'><a href="#">world</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>foo</td>
      <td>bar</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
.highlight td:not(.nostrike) { text-decoration:line-through; }
```

This is usually cleaner when you want everything to have the strike except certain elements.  Instead of adding a span to each with the strike, you can add filter it out when necessary.