# Line through cannot be removed in sublist

Tags: html, css

The following code show have two nested lists. The outer one with text-decoration:line-through property and the other with no line through. How can I remove this inner line-through or not apply it in the first place?!! I want line-through on the word "outer" but not "inner"

```
    <DOCTYPE html>
<header><style>
ol li {text-decoration:line-through; color:red;}
ol li ul li{text-decoration:none; color:pink;}

</style></header>
<body>
    <ol>
        <li>Outter
            <ul>
                <li>
                    Inner
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ol>
</body>
```

Comment: are you trying to remove the line-through from the inner or outer or both?

Comment: Looks like it can't be done. Really surprising actually:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/1823388/1977420

Comment: @idotpdot It CAN be done. See [my own answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17347691/1529630) of the same question you linked.

Comment: Agreed. You found a great solution. I posted a link to yours on a few of the similar posts out there (including the one I linked). Well done, I voted you up.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `display: inline-block` to avoid parent's `text-decoration` affecting its children.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/3cbxj/)

It works because, according to the [specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#propdef-text-decoration),

> When specified on or propagated to
>   an inline element, it affects all the boxes generated by that element,
>   and is further propagated to any in-flow block-level boxes that split
>   the inline (see section 9.2.1.1). But, in CSS 2.1, it is undefined
>   whether the decoration propagates into block-level tables. For block
>   containers that establish an inline formatting context, the
>   decorations are propagated to an anonymous inline element that wraps
>   all the in-flow inline-level children of the block container. For all
>   other elements it is propagated to any in-flow children. Note that
>   text decorations **are not propagated** to floating and absolutely
>   positioned descendants, **nor to the contents of atomic inline-level
>   descendants such as inline blocks and inline tables**.

Comment: Thank you it works!! But whyyyy did I have to do that?? Can you explain please?

Comment: you saved my life, thanks.