# Remove underline from part of a link

Tags: css

With this:

```css
a sup {
    text-decoration: none !important;
    color: red;
```

```html
<a href="http:/example.com//">Example<sup class='tm'>&trade;</sup></a>
```

Is it possible to remove the underline from the `<sup>` element? The css is clearly targeting the right element (it turns it red), but the `text-decoration` is ignored. Is there anyway use underline for only *part* of an `a` tag?

Comment: `sup { display: inline-block }`.

Comment: @Oriol: That actually works. Not sure the dupe applies here. The underline is applied to the `a` tag and cascades to the child elements even if they are marked not to.

Comment: It's not cascading. It's like backgrounds: if you use `background: transparent` on an element, you will see the background of its parent. Here it happens the same: you can remove the decoration, but the decoration of the parent is still visible. There are some ways to prevent this behavior, as I explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17347691/1529630).

Comment: Now I think you are right and the questions are different enough, even if the underlying issue is the same. [Unable to un-line-through a nested element](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6566653/1529630) is better.

Comment: @Oriol: Ok. If you want to add your answer, I'll accept it. My alternative of setting `text-decoration: none;` on the `a` and then putting the part I want underlined in a `span` and setting its `text-decoration: underline` works too, but is clearly inferior.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is that [`text-decoration`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#propdef-text-decoration) propagates to descendants:

> When specified on or propagated to an inline element, it affects all
>   the boxes generated by that element, and is further propagated to any
>   in-flow block-level boxes that split the inline [...]
>
> For block containers that establish an inline formatting context, the
>   decorations are propagated to an anonymous inline element that wraps
>   all the in-flow inline-level children of the block container.
>
> For all other elements it is propagated to any in-flow children.

But there are two exceptions: [out-of-flow](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#x23) and [atomic inline-level](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#x13) descendants:

> Note that text decorations are not propagated to floating and
>   absolutely positioned descendants, nor to the contents of atomic
>   inline-level descendants such as inline blocks and inline tables.

Therefore, you can use `display: inline-block` on a child to prevent its parent's `text-decoration` from affecting it.

```css
a > sup {
  display: inline-block; /* Remove parent's text-decoration */
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="http:/example.com//">
  Example<sup class='tm'>&trade;</sup>
</a>
```