# How to override CSS :hover?

Tags: css

I have this HTML code:

```
<ul>
    <li>Line 1</li>
    <li class="disabled">Line 2</li>
</ul>
```

And the corresponding CSS is:

```
ul li:hover {
    color: red;
}
```

This allows for both `li`s to be hovered over and have their color changed. But if I want one of them to be `disabled`, I’d use the following:

```
.disabled {
    color: grey;
}
```

But the other CSS code’s `hover` pseudo-class still has effect. Is there any way I can override this?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The first rule overrides it because of [CSS specificity](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/specificity/), i.e. it's more specific.

Change second rule to:

```css
ul li.disabled, ul li.disabled:hover{
    color:grey;
}
```

Comment: Using !important can come back to bite you, @Procrammer 's approach is a better option.

Comment: Won't work if the item should be grey all the time not just on hover: http://fiddle.jshell.net/88Z5Q/1/

Comment: I also found out that it would be worthwhile to use something like `ul li:not(.disabled):hover{color:red}` - That would apply the hover effect to all li elements which do not have the class .disabled added...

Comment: Related note: "text-decoration" cannot be overridden. - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481318/css-text-decoration-property-cannot-be-overridden-by-child-element

Answer (score 11):

Change your CSS To:

```
ul li:hover{
    color:red;
}

.disabled ,.disabled:hover{
    color:grey;
}
```

[See this fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/88Z5Q/)

**Updating for the 2020s**, you can now use `:not` to your advantage

```css
.disabled {
    color:grey;
}

ul li:not(.disabled):hover{
    color:red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>Line 1</li>
    <li class="disabled">Line 2</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change your css:

> ul li:hover{
>       color:red; }
>
> ul li.disabled,ul li.disabled:hover{
>       color:grey; }

You have to disable the hover effect, so you give it the same color as when it wasn't hovered.

Answer (score 0):

```
.disabled{
    color:grey !important;
}
```

Comment: Try and avoid using !important where possible. It can lead to maintenance issues.

Comment: I agree... Though this does fix the example, the development case will need more finesse...

Comment: Why it should be avoided? Can you give me a link with description?

Comment: In larger projects you can end with a ball mud where everyone tries to override styles. Using !important is a sign for having bad structured CSS. First they try to using longer selectors and at the end you have bunch of !important statements. So !important isn't evil but its indicates that your CSS isn't well structured. Take a look at OOCSS and this blog: http://www.stubbornella.org/ to learn more about on how to build css that scales.

Answer (score -1):

I was trying to get a CSS "disabled" effect to be applied automatically when doing the following javascript:

```
  document.getElementById("TheButton").disabled = true;
```

If "TheButton" is defined with the class "TheClass":

```
  .TheClass { background-color: LightBlue; }
  .TheClass:hover { background-color: Cyan; }
```

The only thing that worked for me was with this CSS:

```
  .TheClass[disabled]            { background-color: lightgrey; } /* for IE */
  .TheClass[disabled='disabled'] { background-color: lightgrey; } /* for Chrome */
  .TheClass[disabled]:hover            { background-color: lightgrey; } /* for IE */
  .TheClass[disabled='disabled']:hover { background-color: lightgrey; } /* for Chrome */
```

Answer (score -1):

Minimum, if only need grey at every time, no need :hover on .disabled

```
ul li:hover{
  color:red;
}
ul li.disabled{// Last rule precedence
   color:grey;
}
```

Or for speed updating, use !important:

```
.disabled{
  color:grey !important;
}
ul li:hover{
   color:red;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can just do following in the *css* to discard any color for disabled elements while we hover on it.

```
ul li:hover:not(:disabled) {
        color: red;
    }
```

This will cause the color *red* to be applied only when list is not disabled.

Comment: `:active` means "while being clicked on" (ish) not "while not disabled"