# Mouse hover and click to display text with CSS and JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Currently I have this: http://jsfiddle.net/TW2Le/95/

I want to be able to click the box to display the text, then click anywhere else to hide the text. One click = `show`, 2nd click anywhere else = `hide`. (This part works)

When it is not "clicked", it should show the text when I hover over, but it should not display the text on top of the old text when I hover it while it is clicked.

i am running into a problem, where it displays double the text when I hover over while it is clicked. I have no idea how to disable "hover" while it is under the `show` condition. It should not repeat the same texts.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7035407/how-to-override-css-hover

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/q3NMK/)

**JS**

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on('click', function(e) {
        if ( $(e.target).closest('.wrap').length ) {
             $('.show').slideToggle();
            $('.noshow').slideToggle(); 
            $(".here").addClass("hide");
        }else{
            $('.show').slideDown();
            $('.noshow').slideUp();
            $(".here").removeClass("hide");
        }
    });
});
```

**Add new CSS rule**

```
.wrap:hover .here.hide {
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: the problem with that is, I can't get it to hover show after one use

Comment: @Jenny Updated solution.

Comment: Ha, I guess you posted this while I was writing my answer. Pretty much the same answer.

Answer (score 3):

http://jsfiddle.net/TW2Le/97/

Try this.

```
$('.wrap').removeClass('reveal');

$('.wrap').addClass('reveal');
```

I added these into your jquery so that when "show" is visible, hovering does nothing.

Comment: thank you both, very helpful! Wish I could accept both answers!

Comment: His was more thorough ;) No worries. Glad to help.