# Hover effect in between the selected start date and end date in css

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, calendar

I am working on a [website](http://ferhan.ferohost.com/) in which I want the **hover effect to be place** `(as shown below in an image)` **in between the selected (Suppose July 26th)** `start date` **and the dates which we will select** on the `end date`:

[image]

The HTML and JS/JQuery code which I have used are as follows:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="dates">
   <div class="start_date" style="width:50%;margin-right:3%;">
      <input readonly="readonly" class="form-control start_date  mb-4" type="text" placeholder="start date" id="startdate_datepicker">
   </div>
   <div class="end_date" style="width:50%;margin-left:3%;">
      <input readonly="readonly" class="form-control  end_date  mb-4" type="text" placeholder="end date" id="enddate_datepicker">
   </div>
</div>
```

**JS/JQuery code:**

```
let startDateUI = $("#startdate_datepicker").datepicker({
  numberOfMonths:[1, 2],
  todayHighlight: true,
  beforeShowDay: function (calDate) {
      return calDate - new Date() < 0 ? [false, '', ''] : [true, '','']
  }
});
$("#enddate_datepicker").datepicker({
  numberOfMonths:[1, 2],
  todayHighlight: true,
  beforeShowDay: function (calDate) {
      let selectedStartDate = $( "#startdate_datepicker" ).datepicker( "getDate" )
      return calDate - selectedStartDate < 0 ? [false, 'disable-day', 'not available day!!!'] : [true, '','']
  }
});
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what code I need to add in the CSS so that **hover comes in effect in between the selected start date and the end date** which the users will select from the `end date section` similar to airbnb website.

Comment: Do you have an example of your css code?

Comment: @Dennis All my css codes are behind the domain (CTRL+U, I am pretty sure you know it). I have accepted the answer of Sphinx. You can have a look.

Comment: yes I thought about that, but I tought, maybe it is a part of the css what is usefull. Thanks for solution! Good luck with your site

Comment: @Dennis I have a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51560956/how-to-make-a-form-which-searches-an-item-around-a-specific-radius). I am wondering if you can have a look and give me some pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is one simple demo for highlight days between start date and hover date.

**The steps:**

1. remove class=`highlight-day` from all `.ui-datepicker-calendar tr td.highlight-day`
2. find out all `.ui-datepicker-calendar tr td` then loop&add css class=`highlight-day` until reach the hover date.
3. uses css selector `.highlight-day a:not(.disable-day)` to highlight the days.

```js
let startDateUI = $("#startdate_datepicker").datepicker({
  numberOfMonths:[1, 2],
  todayHighlight: true,
  beforeShowDay: function (calDate) {
      return calDate - new Date() < 0 ? [false, '', ''] : [true, '','']
  }
});
$("#enddate_datepicker").datepicker({
  numberOfMonths:[1, 2],
  todayHighlight: true,
  beforeShowDay: function (calDate) {
      let selectedStartDate = $( "#startdate_datepicker" ).datepicker( "getDate" )
      return calDate - selectedStartDate < 0 ? [false, 'disable-day', 'not available day!!!'] : [true, '','']
  }
});

$("#enddate_datepicker").datepicker('widget').on('mouseover', 'tr td', function () {
  if(!$( "#startdate_datepicker" ).datepicker( "getDate" )){
    return
  }//this is hard code for start date
  let calendarId = $(this).closest('.ui-datepicker').attr('id')
  
  // clear up highlight-day class
  $('#' + calendarId + ' .ui-datepicker-calendar tr td.highlight-day').each((index, item) => {
    $(item).removeClass('highlight-day')
  })
  
  // loop& add highligh-day class until reach $(this)
  let tds = $('#' + calendarId + ' .ui-datepicker-calendar tr td')
  for(let index = 0; index < tds.size(); ++index) {
    let item = tds[index]
    $(item).addClass('highlight-day')

    if($(item)[0].outerHTML === $(this)[0].outerHTML) {
      break
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.disable-day{
  color: gray;
}
.highlight-day a:not(.disable-day) {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.bootcss.com/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="dates">
   <div class="start_date" style="width:50%;margin-right:3%;">
      <input readonly="readonly" class="form-control start_date  mb-4" type="text" placeholder="start date" id="startdate_datepicker">
   </div>
   <div class="end_date" style="width:50%;margin-left:3%;">
      <input readonly="readonly" class="form-control  end_date  mb-4" type="text" placeholder="end date" id="enddate_datepicker">
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I will let you know if I have any other question similar to that.

Comment: I am thinking that if there is a way we can put a geographic location for any product being searched. Suppose I am searching for a calculator then as soon as I hit `search radius` placeholder, a popup should appear at the bottom stating that till what radius I need to search for a product. I have posted my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51560956/how-to-make-a-form-which-searches-an-item-around-a-specific-radius). Let me know if we can do that in js/juqery.