# Prevent parent underline from underlining child element

Tags: html, css

Given this pared-down test case:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><title>No Underline Please</title>
<style type="text/css">
  li       { text-decoration:underline        }
  li .rule { text-decoration:none ! important }
</style>
</head><body>
  <ol><li><span class="rule">RULE</span> CONTENT</li></ol>
</body></html>
```

I want to underline CONTENT but not underline RULE. However, Chrome, FF, and IE9 all underline RULE. Presumably this is standards-compliant behavior, given that they all agree.

1. What spec am I forgetting that is preventing me from overriding the `text-decoration`?
2. How can I achieve the result I want?

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/F3Grr/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481318/css-text-decoration-property-cannot-be-overridden-by-ancestor-element/4481356#4481356

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The entire `li` element is being underlined. The `li.rule` rule is being rendered, but the underline applies to the entire list item.

You should wrap the content you want to be underlined inside another inline element. Here's one example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><title>No Underline! You're welcome.</title>
<style type="text/css">
  li span.emphasis { text-decoration:underline; }
</style>
</head><body>
  <ol><li>RULE <span class="emphasis">CONTENT</span></li></ol>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Thanks, I just realized the same thing. I'll accept your answer in 9 minutes _if_ you change the class name to [not describe the visual style being applied](http://phrogz.net/CSS/HowToDevelopWithCSS.html#semanticselector). ;)

Comment: Haha, but you're ok with me indenting like that? Illustrative code differs from production code, imho.

Comment: Note that while your answer (wrap the content you want to underline) is the correct workaround for this problem, as shown by [this test](http://jsfiddle.net/F3Grr/8/) we can see that `text-decoration` accumulates on descendants (rather than being inherited by them).

Comment: Also interesting to note is [this comment](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/text-decoration): "Firefox versions up to and including 3.5; Safari up to and including version 4; Chrome up to and including version 3; all propagate text decoration values to floating descendants." Even the modern browsers are not properly honoring the specs.