# How to remove only underline from a:before?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, pseudo-element, text-decorations

I have a set of styled links using the `:before` to apply an arrow.

It looks good in all browser, but when I apply the underline to the link, I don't want to have underline on the `:before` part (the arrow).

See jsfiddle for example: http://jsfiddle.net/r42e5/1/

Is it possible to remove this? The test-style I sat with `#test p a:hover:before` does get applied (according to Firebug), but the underline is still there.

Any way to avoid this?

```css
#test {
  color: #B2B2B2;
}

#test p a {
  color: #B2B2B2;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#test p a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

#test p a:before {
  color: #B2B2B2;
  content: "► ";
  text-decoration: none;
}

#test p a:hover:before {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <p><a href="#">A link</a></p>
  <p><a href="#">Another link</a></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, you obviously want a list... Use an UL element instead of the DIV/P combination. With lists you get the bullets (or discs, ... ) for free...

Comment: Why not to use list with custom bullets instead of paragraphs in your case? Otherwise apply before-content to parent p, not to link itself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8536015/before-on-link-stop-before-content-being-underlined-on-hover/17346595#17346595

Answer (score 197, accepted):

> Is it possible to remove this?

Yes, if you change the display style of the inline element from `display:inline` (the default) to `display:inline-block`:

```css
#test p a:before {
    color: #B2B2B2;
    content: "► ";
    display:inline-block;
}
```

This is because [the CSS specs say](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#propdef-text-decoration):

> When specified on or propagated to an inline element, it affects all the boxes generated by that element, and is further propagated to any in-flow block-level boxes that split the inline (see section 9.2.1.1). […] For all other elements it is propagated to any in-flow children. Note that text decorations are **not propagated** to floating and absolutely positioned descendants, nor **to the contents of atomic inline-level descendants such as inline blocks and inline tables**.

(Emphasis mine.)

### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/r42e5/10/

<sub>*Thanks to @Oriol for providing the workaround that prompted me to check the specs and see that the workaround is legal.*</sub>

Comment: You can override a `text-decoration:underline` applied to a parent element with `display:inline-block`. See an example: http://jsfiddle.net/aZdhN/1/ . Then, asker's problem can be solved like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17347068/1529630

Comment: As far as I can see, this does not work in Internet Explorer (tested 8-10). Any ideas how to deal with IE?

Comment: I've found a solution that is working in IE8-11 too:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/21902566/1607968

Answer (score 55):

There is a **Bug in IE8-11**, so using `display:inline-block;` alone won't work there.

I've found a solution for this bug, by explicitly setting `text-decoration:underline;` for the :before-content and then overwrite this rule again with `text-decoration:none;`

```
a {text-decoration:none;}
a:hover {text-decoration:underline;}
a:before {content:'>\a0'; text-decoration:underline; display:inline-block;}
a:before,
a:hover:before {text-decoration:none;}
```

Working example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/95C2M/

Update: 
Since jsfiddle does not work with IE8 anymore, just paste this simple demo-code in a local html file and open it in IE8:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>demo</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        a {text-decoration:none;}
        a:hover {text-decoration:underline;}
        a:before {content:'>\a0'; text-decoration:underline; display:inline-block;}
        a:before,
        a:hover:before {text-decoration:none;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#">Testlink</a> With no Underline on hover under before-content
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Had a case were **IE8 underlining** of a hyperlinked image could only be turned off by `<img style="text-decoration:underline">` inside (and here was the key) `<a style="padding:0; border:none;">`

Comment: Unfortunately that jsfiddle can't be verified in IE8 because jsfiddle doesn't work in IE8.

Comment: Unfortunately I could not find any online code sharing tool that still works with IE8. I've added a code snipped to the answer above which you can just paste into an html file and open it locally in IE8.

Comment: Tested and approved on IE9, event without two different states.

Comment: Had a link with an icon in :before that was supposed to NOT be underlined in resting state, then be underlined on hover, but not the icon.
Here is what I had to do to convince IE to get this right:
a {text-decoration: none}
a:before {text-decoration: underline}
a:before {text-decoration: none} (yes really, first underline, then overwrite with none)
a:hover {text-decration: underline}
a:hover:before {text-decoration: none}

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me on IE11 without additional markup. Thanks!

Comment: I don't get why it's working. It's so dumb, that I can't stop laughing but more important it has solved my problem. I've tried also other solutions but with no success. Thanks.

Comment: Sadly doesn't seem to work in combination with :nth-child in IE. Edit: Never mind! As long as you set the style before the nth-loop its fine!

Answer (score 9):

You can do it adding the following to the `:before` element:

```
display: inline-block;
white-space: pre-wrap;
```

With `display: inline-block` the underline disappears. But then the problem is that the space after the triangle collapses and is not shown. To fix it, you can use `white-space: pre-wrap` or `white-space: pre`.

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/r42e5/9/

Comment: +1 for the `pre-wrap` hint. I was using `content:'►\a0'` (\a0 = &nbsp;)

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your links in spans and add the text-decoration to the span on the a:hover like this,

```
a:hover span {
   text-decoration:underline;
}
```

I have updated your fiddle to what I think you are trying to do. http://jsfiddle.net/r42e5/4/

Comment: Good idea. That was how I did it before. The problem is that this link is produced in a cms-system and our customers are filling this in as rich-text themselves.

Comment: what language is the CMS? Could get it to spit out link and then wrap it in a span before sending it to the browser?

Comment: The company is using modx. I guess I could do that as a last way out, but I really wanted to void that. Guess it's not possible. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score -3):

try using instead:

```
#test p:before {
    color: #B2B2B2;
    content: "► ";
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

will that do?

Comment: I have may paragraphs in my div, so that won't work. Good idea tho.

Answer (score -5):

use this

```
#test  p:before {
    color: #B2B2B2;
    content: "► ";

}
```

Comment: does not do anything. the text-decoration is ignored.