# Why a:before gets underlined

Tags: css, list, html-lists, underline

How can I remove the underline bellow "-"? I only want the text to be underlined on Hover not the "-"

[**-- DEMO --**](http://jsfiddle.net/uLrqatj8/)

Many thanks!

**HTML**

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li>
      <a href="#">Commercial Property Management</a>
         <ul>
            <li>
               <a href="#">Industrial</a>
             </li>
              <li>
                 <a href="#">Office</a>
               </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">Retail</a>
                   </li>
              <li>
                        <a href="#">Shopping Centres</a>
                    </li>
                    </ul>
                     </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Mixed-Use Residential Property Management</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul.menu li li a:before {
    content: "-";
    margin-right: 8px;
}
```

Comment: Did you try to set text-decoration: none; for a:before?

Comment: Because the :before pseudo element is added "before" the **content** of the `a` not in front of the `a` tag

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove only underline from a:before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8820286/how-to-remove-only-underline-from-abefore)

Comment: @DoodlebunchYup I tried a:before. It doesn't work.

Comment: Because even though it is called `before` it is actually inserted inside the `a` and hence inherits the parent's setting. From MDN - **::before creates a pseudo-element that is the first child of the element matched**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Edit 4 years later:** This answer is pretty much a low-quality duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/8820459/3285730. I'd recommend going there and getting an actual explanation.

Try giving it `display:inline-block;`:

```
ul.menu li li a:before {
    content: "-";
    margin-right: 8px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2z94r8Lu/)

Comment: display:inline-block did the job. Great. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`content` of the `:before` selector is counted to the `a`-tag as it creates a pseudo-element within the element.

Add `display:inline-block;` to the definition to solve this issue.