# IE:11 hover on before not working

Tags: css, css-selectors, internet-explorer-11, pseudo-element

My link has below structure:

```
a{
  // some css here
}
a:before{
 // contains font icon
}
a:hover{
 text-decoration:underline;
}
a:hover:before{
 text-decoration:none;
}
```

I need to add `text-decoration:underline` only on hover of a link, not on the before part. My code is working perfectly fine on chrome but on IE 11, `text-decoration:none` is not working for `a:hover:before`.

Comment: The ::before pseudo-element is a (pseudo) child of the <a>, in other words, inside it, so all of the features of the <a> itself will still be there, including the underline. (You may notice that hovering works too if you hover only on the ::before.)

Comment: Related to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21902566/4108884.

Comment: By the way, I made [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/8ezdqo3w/), but I don't see any difference between the browsers: the ::before gets underlined in all of them.

Comment: @Mr Lister: Presumably, the pseudo-comments in the given CSS are hiding all the layout information necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @BoltClock Ah, you mean that with some clever CSS, it would be possible to replicate the OP's findings? But of course! Here, I made [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/ym9fj762/) that behaves like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is put the main content of the `<a>` in a span, and underline only the span.

```css
a {
  text-decoration:none;
}
a:before {
 content: '➠ ';
}
a:hover span {                 /* changed */
 text-decoration:underline;
}
a:hover:before {
 text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#"><span>Click here</span></a>
```