# Link with icon ::before where icon should have no underline - display: inline-block is no option?

Tags: html, css, anchor

My link should look like this:

```
> My link text
  ____________
```

while "My link text" should be underlined and the content in the ::before part should not be.

I tried it like this:

```
a {
   text-decoration: underline;
}

a::before {
   content: ">";
   text-decoration: none;
}
```

But no success. It's always underlined. What can I do?

**EDIT:
One answer was, that I should simply add display: inline-block to the ::before part. BUT the problem I am getting with this is, that the links breaks somethimes after the icon. I definitly need to avoid that. And the solution I have found for that is to REMOVE the display: inline-block.  So, for the one or the other I need another solution. display: inline-block is not the right one.**

Comment: display:inline-block to before

Comment: Add `float:left` to `a::before{.....}`.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `display: inline-block` on the pseudo element (`::before`) will allow it to not inherit the `text-decoration`.

See https://codepen.io/RonnyO/pen/vYGvNWp?editors=1100

Already explained in detail [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8820459/324094).

Comment: *Already explained in detail elsewhere.* --> for this particular reason we need to close question as duplicate (you have enough reputation to do it)

Comment: Correct, after I've answered I looked it up and you beat me to the closing vote :-)

Comment: Please see my edit note as well. The problem is not solved

Comment: stack overflow user try not to close as duplicate challenge (impossible)