# :hover:before text-decoration none has no effects?

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

As title, I'm adding icons using `.icon-*`. When adding an icon to an hyperlink:

```
<a href="#" class="icon-email icon-large">Email me!</a>
```

The content inserted by `content` property shows the underline text-decoration on hover. I'd like to disable the `text-decoration` only for the content before:

```css
[class^="icon-"]:before, [class*=" icon-"]:before {
    font-family: 'IcoMoon';
    font-style: normal;
    speak: none;
}
.icon-mail:before {
    content: "\37";
}
[class^="icon-large-"]:before, [class*=" icon-large"]:before {
    font-size: 48px;
    line-height: 48px;
}
a[class^="icon-"]:before, a[class*=" icon-"]:before {
    margin-right: 5px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

I've tried this but it's not working (decoration is still visible):

```
a[class^="icon-"]:hover:before, a[class*=" icon-"]:hover:before {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: You can't do that with pseudoelements. You're going to have to use JS.

Comment: Yea you cannot double-up pseusoelements and pseudoclasses like that without js. I would suggest using javascript to handle the :before rather than to handle the :hover. That is because :before is not supported by all browsers. But that's just my 2 cents..

Comment: @BumbleB2na at least IE8+, FF10.0.2+, Opera 11.61+, Safari 5.1.2+, Chrome 17 http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html

Comment: @BumbleB2na: You can - the pseudo-element just has to be the last in the selector.

Comment: I notice some typos in the class and attribute selectors, not that these would relate to the issue at hand. Notably, your `icon-large` attribute selectors can simply be changed to `.icon-large:before` (but I'm assuming you only have that as a standalone class and not as a prefix for other classes).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

As [the `:before` pseudo-element is rendered as a descendant box](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#before-after-content) (more specifically, just before the first child content box) of its generating element, it obeys [the same rules its normal descendant boxes do with respect to `text-decoration`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#lining-striking-props):

> The 'text-decoration' property on descendant elements cannot have any effect on the decoration of the ancestor.

See these answers for more details:

- [CSS text-decoration property cannot be overridden by child element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481318/css-text-decoration-property-cannot-be-overridden-by-child-element/4481356#4481356)
- [How do I get this CSS text-decoration override to work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823341/how-do-i-get-this-css-text-decoration-override-to-work/1823388#1823388)

There isn't any good way around this... the only alternatives that come immediately to mind are:

- Wrap the text in its own `span` element, then apply `text-decoration` to that `span`, [as shown by skip405](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11474780/hoverbefore-text-decoration-none-has-no-effects/11477421#11477421). The disadvantage is, of course, extra markup.
- Use an inline block background image instead of inline text in an icon font with your `:before` pseudo-element (I've also corrected the inconsistencies with your class selectors):

  ```css
  [class^="icon-"]:before, [class*=" icon-"]:before {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 1em;
      height: 1em;
      background-size: contain;
      content: "";
  }
  .icon-email:before {
      background-image: url(icon-mail.svg);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }
  .icon-large:before {
      width: 48px;
      height: 48px;
  }
  a[class^="icon-"]:before, a[class*=" icon-"]:before {
      margin-right: 5px;
      vertical-align: middle;
  }
  ```

  The advantage this has over skip405's solution is that you don't have to modify the HTML, but given that it uses [SVG vector background images](http://caniuse.com/svg-css) and [`background-size`](http://caniuse.com/background-img-opts), it won't work in IE8.

  If you do need IE8 support, then you have to fall back to bitmap images:

  ```css
  .icon-email:before {
      background-image: url(icon-mail.png);
  }
  .icon-email.icon-large:before {
      background-image: url(icon-mail-large.png);
  }
  ```

Comment: Really thanks for your time and your great explanation. I'll go for the extra markup solution.

Comment: See below for a more recent up to date answer.

Answer (score 58):

Insert display:inline-block; in your css. Something like the one below:

```
.icon-mail:before {
    content: "\37";
    display:inline-block;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Here is the JS FIDDLE:

http://jsfiddle.net/73p2k/18/

Comment: Thank you so much for this trick. Never would have thought of adding it.

Comment: @acme, please see the latest jsfiddler for IE support. Tested in IE9 http://jsfiddle.net/73p2k/18/

Comment: So for IE you have to set `text-decoration:underline;` to `a:before` AND `text-decoration:none;` to `a:hover:before`. It seems to be a [bug](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21902566/1607968). Thx Pinoy2015!

Comment: What?? This actually worked... and only for inline-block.... Can you explain why does it behave that way, and how did you get to this conclusion?

Comment: In my case, this was the actual solution.

Answer (score 4):

A pseudoelement selector must be the last item in a selection chain.

You can apply a style to `element:hover:before` but not to `element:before:hover`.

Comment: It is indeed... title is wrong, question is correct. Going to fix it.

Answer (score 4):

You can set height & overflow:hidden for :before element, and text-decoration will not be visible  :)

Answer (score 2):

Tried some things using just the `a` tag as a markup, but alas. A possible workaround for you may be to inner wrap the link in another element, a `span`, for instance. Thus you can have the underline on this element (instead of a pseudoelement) - which is perfectly controlled by css.

A live example is here: http://jsfiddle.net/skip405/fQHUH/

Answer (score 1):

This solution worked for me. It excluedes the pseude-elements.
But for this you need to wrap the content of the `<a>` tag into an extra element.

```
a:hover { text-decoration: none; }
a:hover > * { text-decoration: underline; }


<a href="#"><span>content</span></a>
```