# Material design icon vertical-align, chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, material-design, vertical-alignment

We are using Material Design Icons, but the vertical alignment of icons is very odd...Therefore I changed the vertical alignment of the icon to bottom.

But when the text and icon are inside a link, the underline property of the icon is drawn lower then the underline of text in Chrome. In Firefox everything works as expected.

Is there is a better way to position the material design icons properly? Or how can I solve the issue of the underline being drawn at the incorrect position?

```
a {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

a:before {
  content: "\E315";
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

See this jsfiddle for full sample: 
https://jsfiddle.net/uumn0bbt/3/

Thanks!
Stijn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could rebuild the `text-decoration: underline` within the pseudo `:after` element using `border-bottom`.

Here is an example.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons');


a {
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
}

a:before {
  content: "\E315";
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

a:after {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 1px;
  border-width: 0 0 1px;
  border-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">underline, icon v-align bottom</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Text decoration **will not work** on :pseudo elements, as you can see if you try this code (you can find an [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11474780/hoverbefore-text-decoration-none-has-no-effects) here):

```
a:before {
    content: "\E315";
    font-family: 'Material Icons';
    margin-top: 5px;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

So let me **paste** what has been suggested there:

> - Wrap the text in its own span element, then apply text-decoration to    that span
> - Use an inline block background image instead of inline text in an
>     icon font with your :before pseudo-element

In other words, you will need to add an extra code, while you could also try **using lists** and adding those icons as list-style-image, but then you wouldn't be using fonts at all, so the outcome could be distorted images if the viewer is zooming.

Answer (score 0):

```css
a.bottom:after { /* changed before to after */
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Does that helps to solve your problem?