# Text decoration for link and span inside this link

Tags: css, text-decorations

I have links like:

```
<a href="#">Link text<span>Link sub-text</span></a>
```

When hovering I need that text inside span is not decorated with underline (but main link text is). Is it possible?
I've tried:

```
a:hover span {text-decoration:none;}
```

This is not working.

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Just figured it out, I just need to place main link text inside span and sub-link text outside link span like:
`<a href="#"><span>Link text</span>sub-text</a>`

and CSS:`a:hover {text-decoration:none;}
a:hover span {text-decoration:underline;}`

This worked for me.

Comment: Related: [CSS text-decoration property cannot be overridden by child element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481318/css-text-decoration-property-cannot-be-overridden-by-child-element) and [How do I get this CSS text-decoration override to work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823341/how-do-i-get-this-css-text-decoration-override-to-work) - these questions explain why `text-decoration none` inside the `span` doesn't work. So yes, your solution is pretty much the only way to get around this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add link text (text you want to be decorated with underline) inside `<span>` and the sub-text outside as normal link text, like:
`<a href="#"><span>Link text</span>sub-text</a>`

To decorate Link text use:

```
a:hover {
  text-decoration:none;
} 
a:hover span {
  text-decoration:underline;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to use the `color` and `border` properties, instead of `text-decoration`. You need to set `text-decoration: none` first, and then use `border-bottom` as the underline for all your links.

**style.css**

```
a, a:link, a:visited
{
color: #11bad3;
text-decoration: none;
border-bottom: 1px solid #11bad3;
}

a:hover, a:active 
{
background: #00a9c2;
border-color: #00a9c2;
color: #fff;
}
```

**print.css**

```
a, a:link, a:visited 
{
border-bottom: 0px;
}
```

**index.html**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css" type="text/css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/print.css" type="text/css" media="print">
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but since I just had the same problem, and came up with a solution, I figured I would write it anyways.

Instead of trying using text-decoration: underline, instead just use border-bottom: 1px solid #000, this way, you can simply say border-bottom: none,

Answer (score -1):

Another solution is to use colors instead of underlines as your identifier:

```
<a id="outer-link" href="#">
    Outer text <span id="inner-text">inner text</span> more outer text.
</a> 

<style>
    a { text-decoration: none; }
    #outer-link:hover { color: green; }
    #outer-link:hover #inner-text { color: red; }
</style>
```