# How do I not underline an element in a link?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to underline the link except for the #myspan element, which I do not want underlined under any circumstance. I'd like to also change #myspan's color. The rules don't seem to apply to it. If I reverse the order and not underline the "a" but underline #myspan it seems to apply the rules. I've seen [Text decoration for link and span inside this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8681301/text-decoration-for-link-and-span-inside-this-link) to no avail.

```css
    a {
      text-decoration: underline;
    }
    
    a #myspan {
      color: black;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    a:active #myspan {
      color: grey;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    a:visited #myspan {
      color: yellow;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    a:hover #myspan {
      color: red;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
```

```html
  <a href="#">A link <span id="myspan">some additional information</span></a>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make the element to be `inline-block` and it won't get affected by the underline:

```css
a {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

a #myspan {
  color: black;
  display:inline-block;
}

a:active #myspan {
  color: grey;
}

a:visited #myspan {
  color: yellow;
}

a:hover #myspan {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">A link <span id="myspan">some additional information</span></a>
```

> Note that text decorations are not propagated to floating and absolutely positioned descendants, nor to the contents of atomic inline-level descendants such as **inline blocks** and inline tables. <sup>[ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html#decoration)</sup>

---

To remove the small space between text and span you can get rid of the whitespace and use a small margin:

```css
a {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

a #myspan {
  color: black;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-left:4px;
}


a:active #myspan {
  color: grey;
}

a:visited #myspan {
  color: yellow;
}

a:hover #myspan {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">A link<span id="myspan">some additional information</span></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#span1{
  text-decoration:underline;
}

#myspan {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none!important;

}

a:active #myspan {
  color: grey;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited #myspan {
  color: yellow;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover #myspan {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Make the above changes to the css.

```
<a href="#"><span id="span1">A link </span><span id="myspan">some additional information</span></a>
```

Make the changes to HTML.

Let me know if it works