# How to remove underline line when hovering a pseudo element inside anchor tag?

Tags: html, css

How can I add hover underline to the `underline` text inside div but not to the pseudo element `no underline`?

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

div:before {
  content: "no underline";
  display: block;
}

div:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<a href="">
  <div>underline</div>
</a>
```

Comment: I see no underline in Chrome or FF

Answer (score 2):

simply like below:

```css
div:before {
  content: "no underline";
  display: inline-block;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<a href="">
   <div>underline</div>
</a>
```

On hover:

```css
div:before {
  content: "no underline";
  display: inline-block;
  width:100%;
}

a {
  text-decoration:none;
}

div:hover { /* OR a:hover */
  text-decoration:underline;
}
```

```html
<a href="">
   <div>underline</div>
</a>
```

Related: [How do I not underline an element in a link?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54816830/8620333)

Answer (score 0):

just add a span tag and then target the span on hover

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

div:before {
  content: "no underline";
  display: block;
}

span:hover{
text-decoration: underline;}
```

```html
<a href="">
   <div><span>underline</span></div>
</a>
```

Comment: The problem is that you've changed the markup, which is against the specs provided.

Comment: why is that a problem?