# CSS line-through is not disabled on nested span

Tags: html, css

CSS :

```
ol {
    margin: 0 30px;
}
    li {
        margin: 15px 0;
    }
    li.done {
        text-decoration: line-through;
    }
    li.done span {
        text-decoration: none;
        background: #ff0;
    }
```

HTML :

```
<ol>
    <li class="done">Hello <span>World</span></li>
    <li>World</li>
</ol>
```

JSFiddle Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/pZye7/5/ . And something weird on JSFiddle, ordered list's numbers are not displayed.

My requirement : the word "World" should not have the line-through on it.

Comment: That's quite strange. And it's cross-browser. Chrome, FF, IE9. Concerning the jsFiddle "oddity": if you uncheck *Normalized CSS*, they will appear. Checking it activates the reset CSS.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481318/css-text-decoration-property-cannot-be-overridden-by-child-element and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823341/how-do-i-get-this-css-text-decoration-override-to-work

Comment: @bažmegakapa & BoltClock  Thank you both for the info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
li.done span {
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #ff0;
    display: inline-block; /* This solved the problem.*/
}
```

Reason: Unknown

Comment: The reason is stated in the two duplicates I link to in the comments above. You simply cannot undo a parent's text decorations within its children.