# How to disable CSS style relatively to a certain parent tag?

Tags: css, html

This is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>span {text-decoration: none}</style>
<body>
<a href="#">underscored text <span>without underscore</span></a>
</body></html>
```

The `<span>` remains underscored. What is a possible workaround (without JavaScript and without changing the HTML)?

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823341/how-do-i-get-this-css-text-decoration-override-to-work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>span {text-decoration: none;display: inline-block;}</style>
<body>
<a href="#">underscored text <span>without underscore</span></a>
</body></html>​
```

Link to original answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/10478962/662250

[**Working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/MTMEj/)

Comment: yeah thats why I gave link to original answer :)

Comment: The reason is explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481318/css-text-decoration-property-cannot-be-overridden-by-child-element), if someone interested

Answer (score 1):

Set it up so that the anchor tag has no underline, but the span DOES have an underline

```
<a href="#"><span>underscored text</span> without underscore</a>

a{
  text-decoration:none;
}

a span{
  text-decoration:underline;
}
```

Comment: I can't change the HTML, only CSS

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way so here is a dirty hack:

```
<html>
<style>
    span {border-bottom:1px solid white;}
    a {text-decoration: none;border-bottom:1px solid blue;}
    </style>
<body>
<a href="#">underscored text <span>without underscore</span></a>
</body></html>​
```

... only because you mentioned you can't change the HTML.