# CSS: direct descedant selector. it selects elements that are not direct children

Tags: css, css-selectors

the direct child selector in css(>) selects the direct descedants and passes color to them, but when it comes to text-decoration, it selects other elements too. How come?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dDJmE

for color i see it selects only the direct descedants, but why is not the behaviour for text-decoration correct? What am i missing?

CSS

```
li {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
ol.numbers > li {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: red;
}
```

HTML

```
  <ol class="numbers">
    <li> First! </li>
    <li> Second! 
       <ul>
        <li> hehe </li>
        <li> huhu 
          <ol>
            <li> nested! </li>
          </ol>
         </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li> Third! </li>
    <li> Fourth! 
      <ol>
       <li> oh lala </li>
      </ol>
    </li>

   </ol>
```

Comment: A note that we ask you to include your code in your question as opposed to linking to it. That way if somebody else looks at this question and the linked code goes away, they can still deduce the solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS text-decoration property cannot be overridden by child element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481318/css-text-decoration-property-cannot-be-overridden-by-child-element)

Comment: Just to make it clear: The problem is not with the selector, it's how `text-decoration` works.

Comment: @Felix Kling: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823341/how-do-i-get-this-css-text-decoration-override-to-work) is probably a closer duplicate. The one I answered directly addresses text decorations, whereas the other one, like this question, has the issue hidden behind an innocuous child selector problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your markup:

```
<div>

  <ol class="numbers">
    <li> First! </li>
    <li> Second! 
       <ul>
        <li> hehe </li>
        <li> huhu 
          <ol>
            <li> nested! </li>
          </ol>
         </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li> Third! </li>
    <li> Fourth! 
      <ol>
       <li> oh lala </li>
      </ol>
    </li>

   </ol>

  <ol class="letters">
    <li> A </li>
    <li> B </li>
  </ol>
```

The (non-specific) `ol` and respective `li` children are simply subjects of styles being applied to any text content within any `ol.numbers>li`. You have to override the styling the non-specified child `ol` and `li`s are inheriting. You can do this with `ol.numbers>li li` as a selector.

*Addition*

Seems I was right about text-decoration not being congruent with other text-styling mechanisms: [How do I get this CSS text-decoration override to work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823341/how-do-i-get-this-css-text-decoration-override-to-work)

You're going to have to approach this problem differently. I would recommend wrapping your text with appropriate tags (`p`s, `span`s, etc.), and addressing them specifically in the CSS to get the desired outcome.

Comment: No, I don't think this would work. The OP is already specifying `text-decoration: none` for all `li` elements. Proof: http://jsfiddle.net/Rqkx2/1/.

Comment: You're right; I'll keep working on it. It seems as though `text-decoration` in particular is a bit quirky in how it handles being overridden (for instance, the text color *does* change to black, expectedly).

Comment: It's a duplicate question, more info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481318/css-text-decoration-property-cannot-be-overridden-by-child-element/4481356#4481356.

Comment: Felix-kling it seems you are right. I never thought text-decoration would be special, so when searching for possible solutions before writing the question, it didn't dawn on me to search specifically for this text-decoration. thank you Felix Kling

Answer (score 1):

It is due to the order that CSS applies styles.  `ol.numbers > li` is more specific than `li`. So that style takes precedence.

Comment: Yeah, that's right. One should search for `'CSS specifity'` in the search engine if your choice.

Comment: This answer doesn't make any sense. CSS shouldn't be giving any other descendants *besides* the direct descendants of `ol.numbers` that underline characteristic, ergo traditional cascading rules are irrelevant.

Comment: @dclowd9901 - yes, this seems to be a bug?

Comment: ol.numbers > li should select only the li elements that are direct children of ol.numbers. But here this is not happening. this was the question :)

Comment: @Vagelis: It *is* happening. If it wasn't the color of the underline would be black.

Comment: No wait. OK, got it: Because the styling is being applied to the parent LI, any content of that LI is going to receive the style, regardless of what it's being contained by. OLs, ULs, spans, p's whatever. It's a style applied to the content of `ol.numbers>li`. You have to override that style with specificity on the children.

Comment: @dclowd9901 - That makes sense. This answer is wrong, but I'm going to leave it up just because the discussion is worthwhile. You should post your own answer.

Comment: so why is 1.hehe and 2.huhu underlined? they are not direct descedants of ol.numbers

Comment: @mrtsherman: I wouldn't even say you were wrong, just that the way the styling is being applied has more to do with the markup hierarchy than specificity, though specificity is the solution to the problem.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the selector. More info in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481318/css-text-decoration-property-cannot-be-overridden-by-child-element/4481356#4481356.