# CSS3 Make a Descendant Element Turn off a Parent's Border Styling

Tags: css, border

I know that text-decoration-skip can be used to make descendant elements turn off their parent's text decorations such as underlining, line-through, and overline, but is there a comparable way to turn off borders in a descendant element?

Example HTML:

```
<p class="border">This text has a border 
    <span class="no_border">and this text doesn't</span></p>
```

Example CSS:

```
.border {
border: 1px solid #FF0000;
}

.no_border {
    /* magic border turn off trickery */
}
```

I would appreciate any method you know of for doing this as I think it would be a very nice effect, but I'm starting to think it may be impossible base on this question: [CSS text-decoration property cannot be overridden by child element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481318/css-text-decoration-property-cannot-be-overridden-by-child-element).

Someone asked why not just add another span element. While That is probably the best solution, and I should probably just start doing it, the reason why I hesitate is because my text is being generated with things like this:

```
$('<p/>', { "id" : "seq_insert_" + i, "class" : arraySeqArrays[i].getBaseType() + " " + arraySeqArrays[i].getFivePrime(), "text" : subsequence } ).add($('<p/>', { "id" : "comp_insert_" + i, "class" : arraySeqArrays[i].getBaseType() + " " + arraySeqArrays[i].getThreePrime(), "text" : subcomplement } )).wrapAll('<td/>').parent().appendTo('#' + subsequenceId);
```

So I can probably figure out a way to add another span to that, but might take me awhile heh.

Comment: Instead of adding a border and then removing it, why not add a span that adds a border to the first bit of text?

Comment: That is probably the easiest way to do this, wish I had thought of it before I wrote out all my jQuery javascript... Added how the text is being generated above.

Answer (score 0):

No, but you could match the border to the background color for a similar effect:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/buPqN/)

```
.no_border {
    border: 1px solid white;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work well, though it was something I tried. It sometimes covers the other border, but often it pokes out. Additionally it will not leave a complete outline which is the desired effect.