# text-decoration:none doesn't remove text decoration

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-specificity

Consider the following code
**HTML:**

`<span class='c1'>Home<sup id='id1'>[2]</sup></span>`

**CSS:**

```
.c1
{
    text-decoration:underline;
}
#id1
{
    text-decoration:none !important;
}
```

Now I expected `Home` to have an underline while the superscript `[2]` doesn't have the underline. But it so happens that the superscript is also getting the underline. What am i missing here??

http://jsfiddle.net/sasidhar/DTpEa/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you think about it, the `sup` isn't underlined. but the `span` still is. Since the `sup` is inside the `span`, you see the underline which appears to be `sup`'s underline.

Consider this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mrchief/DTpEa/24/

You'll see that the `id1` css does take precedence, but you still see the underline which is that of the `span`.

To solve it, have the `sup` outside of the `span`:

```
<span class='c1'>Home</span><sup id='id1'>[2]</sup>
```

Comment: I need a way around this. I don't mind if its webkit specific

Comment: I need the `sup` to remain inside the `span` while not having the underline. Possible?

Comment: You mean you can't rearrange the markup? I'm afraid you need a JS based solution then.

Comment: I would do fine with a js solution too. there is too much mess with the class of the `span`(updated by JS). So i would rather leave the markup as it is.

Comment: Are you using jQuery? If yes, the run this: `$('#id1').detach().insertAfter('span.c1');`. Let me know if you need a more generic solution (that doesn't rely on ids). http://jsfiddle.net/mrchief/DTpEa/25/

Comment: doing that won't apply any styling of `id1` to the `c1` class :(  http://jsfiddle.net/sasidhar/eVRY2/1/

Comment: Here's an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mrchief/eVRY2/2/. What I would advise is instead of styling by id, style the sup by a class. Then you can say: `$('#id1').detach().insertAfter('span.c1').removeClass().addClass('c1 c2');`. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mrchief/eVRY2/3/

Comment: This seems to be a much cleaner approach.......... http://jsfiddle.net/sasidhar/eYXhx/1/

Comment: @sasidhar: Was under the impression that you cannot change the markup. But now it seems that you _can_ and wanted to keep it within the span because you wanted the styles to follow. Had I known that, I'd not have suggested the JS way. :). Anyway, glad that you got it working the simple way!

Comment: It turns out that text-decoration is special, and doesn't cascade like everything else.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a correct variant http://jsfiddle.net/rTUDN/

```
<div>
    <span class='c1'>Home</span>
    <sup id='id1'>[2]</sup>
</div>

.c1
{
    text-decoration:underline;
}
#id1
{
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Comment: Y so? y can't the span element contain further elements? my actual code has more complex styling and is handled by js to add and remove different classes, so i am not interested in removing the superscript from the span

Comment: @sasidhar Text is treated in blocks and styling ignores sub-elements (for the most part).  CSS3's `text-decoration-skip` is designed to deal with this, but it isn't really implemented yet.

Answer (score 1):

How about underlining the sup in the same color as your background?  The span would be underlined and the sup underlining would overlay it.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/sasidhar/eYXhx/1/

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to add

```
display: inline-block;
```

to the object you want to not have the same text-decoration, as below:

```
.c1
{
    text-decoration:underline;
}
#id1
{
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration:none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that text-decoration is special, (and especially annoying) in that it doesn't cascade like other properties.

See: 
[How do I get this CSS text-decoration override to work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823341/how-do-i-get-this-css-text-decoration-override-to-work/1823388#1823388)