# Strange blue underline for text?

Tags: css, hover, underline

```
<p>Text adjustement
 <span>
  - [b](text)[/b] for <b>Bold</b><br>
  - [u](text)[/u] for <u>Underlined</u><br>
  - [i](text)[/i] for <i>Italic</i><br>
  - [s](text)[/s] for <s>Strike</s><br>
  <br>
  - [big](text)[/big] for big text<br>
  - [medium](text)[/medium] for medium-large text<br>
  - [small](text)[/small] for small text<br>
 </span>
</p>
```

```
table.fancy td.tdtop p {
    color: blue;
    display: block;
}

table.fancy td.tdtop p:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;
}

table.fancy td.tdtop p span {
    color: black;
    display: none;
    padding: 2px;
    padding-left: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
    background: #f0f0f0;
    text-decoration: none;
}

table.fancy td.tdtop p:hover span {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none !imporant;
    color: black !imporant;
}
```

I'm trying to get a box to show up when you hover a <p>, but this is what i get:

[image]

Comment: I think this is the one: text-decoration: underline;

Comment: @coder i have that because i want an underline on the `<p>`, but not on the `<span>`.  @BlaXpirit I have.

Comment: can you post a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo and you're saying you need to have underline for <p> and everthing is inside <p>

Comment: @coder http://jsfiddle.net/JRQF4/

Comment: possible duplicate of [text-decoration:none doesn't remove text decoration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7113520/text-decorationnone-doesnt-remove-text-decoration)

Comment: @Juhana Problem is, that i don't want to keep <span> inside <p>, thus the answer of that "duplicate" isn't my answer. So i don't agree in your vote of closing this question.

Comment: I don't understand what your problem is, then. Why can't you just put the "Text adjustment" text inside a span and style that instead of the paragraph?

Comment: @Juhana That makes it inpossible to open the <span> when hovering the <p> with CSS.

Comment: @Thew http://jsfiddle.net/mMAa4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/PYhvc/)**

Is this what you need? problem with css cleaned up.