# Pseudo Element Hover and text-decoration

Tags: css, pseudo-class

Given the following html:

```
<a href="#"><span data-icon="✪"></span>A Link</a>
```

Is it possible to change the `text-decoration` (to none) on hover? The `color` will change, the `text-decoration` will not.

CSS:

```
a { text-decoration: none; }
a:hover{ text-decoration: underline; }
a:hover [data-icon]:before{
  /*Doesn't work*/
  text-decoration: none;

  /*Works*/
  color: red;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nyFxn/1/)

Comment: I don't see the colour red working on the anchor, it is working on the span, text decoration is coming from the anchor and not the span. What is the final result you are looking for? underline on the text and not icon? or ??

Comment: @Huangism I'm wanting no underline on the icon.

Comment: Do you want the underline on the A Link text?

Comment: @Huangism Yes, underline on the link text.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As I explained in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17347691/1529630), you can use `display: inline-block` to prevent `text-decoration` set to an ancestor from propagating to your element:

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
a > [data-icon]:before {
  display: inline-block; /* Avoid text-decoration propagation from `a` */
  content: attr(data-icon);
}
a:hover > [data-icon]:before {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="#"><span data-icon="✪"></span>A Link</a>
```

Comment: the behavior is completely different than the OP fiddle.

Comment: the whole anchor shifts when you hover

Comment: @Huangism I didn't know exactly what the asker wanted, I have updated it. But the main part of my answer is that there's no need to change markup, like you do, because it can be fixed using `display:inline-block`.

Comment: Leading or trailing whitespace is trimmed with `inline-block`, so you'll need extra lateral padding to compensate. Any other ideas?

Comment: @DaviLima Do you mean whitespace in the pseudo-element? Use `white-space: pre` or `pre-wrap` to preserve spaces and tabs.

Comment: @Oriol: worked like a charm, thank you. Much more elegant than using padding ;)  Just to clarify, pre-wrap didn't work because it generated duplicate spaces before my `" - "` pseudo-element (it's a horizontal items separator) and none afterwards. `pre` did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Make things easier and separate it out

http://jsfiddle.net/nyFxn/2/

```
<a href="#"><span data-icon="✪"></span><span class="text">A Link</span></a>
```

CSS

```
a:hover{  text-decoration: none; }
a:hover [data-icon] {

  /*Works*/
  color: red;
}
a:hover .text {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Using `display: inline-block` works in all browsers but IE. To get it to work in IE8+, add `overflow:hidden` to the pseudo element containing the icon.

If the underline still remains in IE, set `line-height: 1` on the pseudo element, so in total you get

```
a [data-icon]:before {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    line-height: 1;
}
```