# How to set underline text for <ul> tag but not <li> tag?

Tags: css

how do i underline the `<ul>` but not `<li>`.

My css is

```
#rightcol { width:170px; min-height:350px; float:right; 
         background:#fff; border:1px solid #666; border-radius:5px; }

#rightcol > ul { list-style:none; line-height:2em; padding-left:0; 
        font-weight:bold; text-decoration:underline; text-align:center; }

#rightcol > ul > li { padding-left:20px; font-weight:normal; 
        font-size:12px; text-decoration:none; text-align:left; }
```

But `<li>` css `"text-decoration:none"` is not working.

Comment: try `text-decoration:none !important;`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get this CSS text-decoration override to work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823341/how-do-i-get-this-css-text-decoration-override-to-work)

Comment: didn't work for me... :(

Comment: "is not working." is not a suitable description of what is not working as expected. And it would be most helpful if you would describe what you want to achieve, because neither your CSS code, nor your question makes any sense. The only allowed children of an `ul` element are `li` elements. So setting a value for the `ul` and negate it for the `li` is somehow "useless".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `display: inline-block` to the `li` tag:

```
#rightcol { width:170px; min-height:350px; float:right; 
         background:#fff; border:1px solid #666; border-radius:5px; }

#rightcol > ul { list-style:none; line-height:2em; padding-left:0; 
        font-weight:bold; text-decoration:underline; text-align:center; }

#rightcol > ul > li { display:inline-block;
        padding-left:20px; font-weight:normal; 
        font-size:12px; text-decoration:none; text-align:left; }
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/6e3WP/

You will need to update the `text-alignment` to ensure that you get the intended results.

Comment: The question is why one should add `text-decoration:underline;` to the UL when it is not wanted in the child LIs!? So the answer should be:"Delete `text-decoration:underline` from the rules!"

Comment: well, actually i wanted to set heading with underline and the menu without underline and underline it only on hover.. i didn't want to use other tags for setting heading in UL. As i was working on it, it didn't work so i just wanted to know if i was doing something wrong.. well, i just used heading tag solve the problem.. The question was jus to know if i was doing something wrong in css.. Thanks all for the help. :)

Answer (score 0):

You may try like this:-

```
#rightcol { width:170px; min-height:350px; float:right; 
         background:#fff; border:1px solid #666; border-radius:5px; }

#rightcol > ul { list-style:none; line-height:2em; padding-left:0; 
        font-weight:bold; text-decoration:underline; text-align:center; }

#rightcol > ul > li { padding-left:20px; font-weight:normal; 
        font-size:12px; text-decoration:none !important; text-align:left; }
```