# How to avoid child elements to get text-decoration style from body element's style

Tags: html, css

HTML example:

```html
<span>line1</span>
<div id="div1" class="no-underline">
    <div id="div2" class="no-underline">subline1</div>
    <div>subline2</div>
</div>
```

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 8px;
    color: rgb(255, 0, 85);
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
#div1 {
    color: black !important;
}
#div2 {
    color: green;
}
.no-underline {
    text-decoration:none !important;
}
```

The result is :

- line1: red and underlined
- subline1: green and underlined
- subline2: black and underlined

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/d3ubknuv/1/)

I want subline1 and subline2 not underlined. But body's style should stay at my case.

How is this possible?

Comment: The `!important` should be next to, a part of, the property-value you're trying to denote as important (`text-decoration: none !important;`), not in little enclosures of their own.

Comment: You are saying that all the things within the `<body>` should be underlined with `text-decoration: underline;`... just delete that bit and use it on the html elements that need it.

Comment: Cannot do that because i want body to have inlinde css .I am using radeditor as email editor and there is a need to be set as default options.

Comment: @Csdtesting I have edited your question because so much inline styles make it unreadable.

Comment: Although i know that inline css is a bad practice , i am trying to use raeditor as email editor and is the way it passes default options.So the structure is something like the sample and i cannot edit that,i have to find a fix to that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get this CSS text-decoration override to work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823341/how-do-i-get-this-css-text-decoration-override-to-work)

Comment: No this is not.We have text-decoration inherited only display : inline-block solves the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get rid of `text-decoration` set on an ancestor using

```css
display: inline-block;
```

Since in your case your elements are blocks, you may also want

```css
width: 100%;
```

to make them more block-like.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/d3ubknuv/)

Answer (score 2):

First I would recommend to avoid using inline Css and !important, that's a bad practice and will make your code very hard to modify later.
one solution would be to put your text decoration on the span:

```
<span style ="text-decoration: underline;">
line1
</span>
```

Comment: Yes i know is a bad practise but i am using radeditor as email editor and is the only way to pass default values.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go! http://jsfiddle.net/41ragvd2/

```
<body style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 8px; color: rgb(255, 0, 85); font-weight: bold; font-style: italic;" >
<span style="text-decoration: underline;">
line1
</span>

<div style="color:black; !important;">
<div style="color:green; !important;">
subline1
</div>

<div>
subline2
</div
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Ok that works for you.But be careful i cannot change body's element inline style at my case.