# css avoid border-bottom on :after

Tags: css

I managed to decorate all links that go outside my website with a little globe, which looks like this:

```
a {border-bottom: 1px dotted silver;}

a:not([href^="http://davidbraun.ch"]):after{
    content: ' O';
    font: 75% 'PantonIcons-BRegular';
    vertical-align: super;
    color:#0b1b3c;
    border-bottom: none !important; /* doesn't work :-( */
}
```

**But:** Can I get it to not have text-decoration (it is the border-bottom 1px dotted from the 1st line)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Preventing `text-decoration` from affecting the descendants is not trivial. However, since you use borders instead of `text-decoration`, it's even more difficult. But still possible.

If your `a` elements are inline (they are by default), you can use `float: right`:

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted silver;
}
a:not([href^="http://davidbraun.ch"]):after {
  content: ' O';
  font: 75%'PantonIcons-BRegular';
  vertical-align: super;
  color: #0b1b3c;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
Foo
<a href="http://example.com">http://stackoverflow.com</a>
Bar
```

But that will move the `::after` too far. So you will need an inline-block wrapper:

```css
.link {
  display: inline-block;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted silver;
}
a:not([href^="http://davidbraun.ch"]):after {
  content: ' O';
  font: 75%'PantonIcons-BRegular';
  vertical-align: super;
  color: #0b1b3c;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
Foo
<span class="link">
  <a href="http://example.com">http://stackoverflow.com</a>
</span>
Bar
```

There is also the `position: absolute` approach:

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted silver;
}
a:not([href^="http://davidbraun.ch"]):after {
  content: ' O';
  font: 75%'PantonIcons-BRegular';
  vertical-align: super;
  color: #0b1b3c;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
Foo
<a href="http://example.com">http://stackoverflow.com</a>
Bar
```

However, now the `::after` will overlap following content, so you should add some `margin-right` to `a`:

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted silver;
  margin-right: .5em;
}
a:not([href^="http://davidbraun.ch"]):after {
  content: ' O';
  font: 75%'PantonIcons-BRegular';
  vertical-align: super;
  color: #0b1b3c;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
Foo
<a href="http://example.com">http://stackoverflow.com</a>
Bar
```

Comment: Oriol, you are my **Hero** :-) thanks very much! all the best - david

Answer (score 1):

You style `a` with `border-bottom`, however you're trying to override it with the [*pseudo-element*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) `::after`, this is actually a different element with its own styles. You should override the `border-bottom` without the `::after`.

Also you don't need `!important` here since `a:not()` has a [*higher specificity*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) than `a`.

```css
a {
  border-bottom: 5px dotted silver;
}
a:not([href^="http://davidbraun.ch"]) {
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="http://davidbraun.ch">http://davidbraun.ch</a>
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">http://stackoverflow.com</a>
```

Comment: This removes the border on all the link. I think OP only wants to remove it on the `::after`.

Answer (score 1):

Note borders are not text decoration. Text decoration is done with [`text-decoration`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration) property:

```css
a {
    text-decoration: underline; /* CSS 2.1 fallback */
    text-decoration: underline dotted silver; /* CSS3 */
}
```

This property usually affects all descendants, even if they have `text-decoration: none`.

But this can be avoided with `display: inline-block`, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17347691/1529630).

```css
a:not([href^="http://davidbraun.ch"]):after {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```css
a {
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration: underline dotted silver;
}
a:not([href^="http://davidbraun.ch"]):after {
  content: ' O';
  font: 75%'PantonIcons-BRegular';
  vertical-align: super;
  color: #0b1b3c;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<a href="http://davidbraun.ch">http://davidbraun.ch</a>
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">http://stackoverflow.com</a>
```

Comment: Well. I know a border is a border and not a text-decoration. I chose to still misuse it as such because it gives me a bit more freedom (spacing and such). Unfortunately it seems that in consequence, I won't get rid of this tiny little bit of border-bottom... But thanks, Oriol and @DanielImms