# CSS attributes being applied to tags outside its parameter

Tags: html, css

I may be understanding this wrong but; I'm using `<ol>` and `<li>` to make a chart. For some reason the CSS I applied to the `<ol>` tag is being applied to the `<li>` tag as well but not all of it, some of the `<li>` CSS attributes are being applied as well, kind of like its takings attributes from both of them. Could someone explain why and a fix please?

https://jsfiddle.net/fdo47tjv/

```css
div.alb1 {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  width: 20%;
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-top: 15%;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  border-right: 40px solid black;
}
div.alb1 ol {
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  margin: 10px;
}
div.alb1 ol li {
  margin: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<body background="./resources/DSC_0146.jpg">

  <div class="alb1">
    <ol>Take Care
      <li>Over My Dead Body</li>
    </ol>
  </div>

</body>
```

**After some fiddling around**
I messed around and changed the css and html so that the 'Take Care' is moved to a paragraph tag outside of the OL and I changed it so a paragraph tag would have the OL attributes that were cited above, and it works fine but this seems unsatisfying, am I cutting a corner?

Comment: If you mean `text-decoration`, then it's not inherited property, so you can't "cancel" it for descendants.

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823341/how-do-i-get-this-css-text-decoration-override-to-work?rq=1 which leads to http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#propdef-text-decoration `The 'text-decoration' property on descendant elements cannot have any effect on the decoration of the ancestor.`

Comment: Placing a text node inside an `<ol>` tag like that is invalid.  You should place your title outside the list or inside a special `<li>` element with it's own style attributes.

Answer (score 0):

OL is li container, so naturally, li are inheriting ol style attributes by default, if you have no styles, you can see that with browsers inspect tool, computed tab and checking Show inherited, that browser by default is handling the inheritance of child style attributes from parent. So to fix that you just need to write li specific styles. If you want to override all inheritances you will see the list of attributes ;-) So good luck. P.S. Read here: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/lists.html because as some comments state you are doing it wrong, text without proper container is just making browser butthurt.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

As other users have mentioned, this is due to the fact that li will inherit the ol styles.

**Fix**

make a separate CSS property just for li at the bottom of your style

```
li {

 font-weight: normal;
 margin: 0; }
```

This will override the properties that were inherited.

Answer (score -3):

The style is being applied because `<li>` is a part of `<ol>`
You may use `<span>` in `<ol>` tag and then apply the style to that `<span>`

Comment: Oh okay, is there an alternative way to have a title and then a list beneath it?

Comment: @stanley updated answer

Comment: Putting `<span>` directly inside `<ol>` would be invalid.