# Text-decoration-color not applying

Tags: html, css

Really simple problem, but it's frustrating me. In the nav bar for the page, I want it to be a color normally and then have a different color hover effect.

When inspecting the element, for some reason the color is being cancelled and I'm not sure why.

[Screenshot of chrome Inspection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCtYZ.png)

```css
.navigation {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 0;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  letter-spacing: .1em;
  text-decoration-color: #ee8719;
  margin: 0;
}

.homenav {
  text-decoration-color: #ffffff;
  color: black;
}

a:hover {
  color: #ad6205;
}

ul li {
  display: inline;
  text-decoration-color: #ee8719;
}
```

```html
<header class="banner">
  <nav class="navigation">
    <ul class="homenav">
      <li>
        <a href="">Projects</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="">Blog</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="">About</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: I was expecting it to make all text within that element the color defined in my text decoration

Comment: Are you attempting to use `text-decoration-color` to change the color of the text? Or is there some decoration you didn't mention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually the defined behavior in [the spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration) for a `text-decoration` style:

> Text decorations draw across descendant elements. This means that it is not possible to disable on a descendant a text decoration that is specified on one of its ancestors.

(More details at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration)

If you want to set your text *color*, then just use the `color` property.

Comment: [It is possible to get rid of text-decoration from an ancestor](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17347691/1529630), though.