# Text decoration for nested li (list) items

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have nested `ul` and `li`. I applied `text-decoration: underline;` for the ancestor `li` and this style is further carried to descendant `li`. In order to remove applied style from descendant `li`, I used another `text-decoration: none !important;` but It does not work. The selector I used is correct and if I change the text-colour, it works.

My question is: Why the `text-decoration: none;` is not working for nested `li` (frogs, toads...). I would appreciate the answer with explanation to understand the reason.

```css
ul li {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
ul li ul li {
    text-decoration: none !important;
    /* It is not working */
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Length: 15-20 inches</li>
  <li>Peak Breeding Activity: March-April</li>
  <li>Typical foods:
    <ul>
      <li>frogs</li>
      <li>toads</li>
      <li>salamanders</li>
      <li>earthworms</li>
      <li>minnows</li>
      <li>mice</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Keep reading until the end of that [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823341/how-do-i-get-this-css-text-decoration-override-to-work), you'll find some workarounds.

Comment: @Pangloss I read that post. I understand now that `text-decoration` is inherited to nested elements. But the suggested method doesn't work. I tried wrapping the nested elements in span but still no lack. The float works but I don't want inline it.

Comment: I guess the simplest way would be using border-bottom instead.

Comment: @Pangloss Thanks got it now.

Answer (score 0):

`ul > li` will only style the direct children of your ul and ignore the nested li's. Use this css selector for items you do not want to be carried all the way through.

Comment: The `text-decoration: underline;` is inherited to nested list.