# Strikethrough a tr excluding some text

Tags: html, css

I have a tr(table row) that needs to be strike through .. but there is some content which should not apply the css so i have created a separate class for it but it does not seem to work ..

**HTML**

```
<tr class="status">
    <td class="content" width="100%" align="left" >
        <span class="subheading">
            sub-Heading
        </span>
        Content
    </td>
</tr>
```

**CSS**

```
.status {
text-decoration: line-through;
}
.status .subheading{
text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

Any ideas or corrections are welcomed ..

Comment: Basically... **you can't** - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36131782/override-text-decoration-on-child-element

Comment: @Rafay - A child cannot override it's parent.... So, not possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per documentation Its not possible ..

https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#lining-striking-props

**Solution:**

**HTML**

```
<tr>
    <td class="content" width="100%" align="left" >
        <span class="subheading">
            sub-Heading
        </span>
        <span class="status">
        Content
        </span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

**CSS**

```
.status {
text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

Yes it creates a messier code ..

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an error in your CSS where your use of '!important' with the .status selector overrides your strikethrough, I would try correcting the CSS like this:

```
.status {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
.subheading{
   text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

Also remember that the property `'text-decoration: line-through;'` only draws a line through text and wont strikethrough a tr or td element.

Comment: if i remove the .status before .subheading this would make the changes to where ever it is called .. which can be correct but its not working .. I included .status because i only want subheading which are under status to apply the css

Answer (score 0):

**CSS**

```
.content span:nth-child(1)
{
text-decoration: line-through;
}
</style>
```

**HTML**

```
<table>
        <tr class="status">
<td class="content" width="100%" align="left" >

        sub-Heading

   <span>Content</span> 
</td>
```

Now i have no idea how many `<td>`'s you have in your `<tr>`. but this is how i got the answer you're looking for in the given code.