# Overriding underline on an element inside another element with underline

Tags: html, css, w3c

my question is almost exactly the same as: [How do I get this CSS text-decoration override to work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823341/how-do-i-get-this-css-text-decoration-override-to-work). But I see that the question is 7 years old and I wonder if we have any method of achieving this now?

Basically I have a structure which looks like this:

```html
<a href='abc'>
  This is underlined <span>But not this.</span>
 </a>
```

I want only the text under `span` to not be underlined. I understand that I can use border bottom and achieve this. Or remove underline from the `a` tag and insert the text which I want underlined in a `span`.

I just want to know if there is a way now after 7 years to override `text-decoration: underline` in a child element.

Comment: If you want to attract new answers to an old question, consider posting a bounty on it. Don't ask a duplicate question.

Comment: @Quentin: Even if the question has an answer which is accepted? I am not sure how bounties work. Excuse my ignorance. I would also not want to loose my reputation and I think this is a fair question.

Answer (score -1):

Use css to achieve what you want.

```css
a span {
    text-decoration: none !important;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<a href='abc'>
  This is underlined <span>But not this.</span>
 </a>
```

Comment: I am sorry if I misunderstood your question. But I thought you wanted to Underline the `this is underlined` text and remove underline from `but not this` text

Comment: @Yathi Have you tried this?  It does work.  You can see that in the snippet, too.

Comment: @sh0ber: Yes. It does work for the snippet which I find even more confusing. But on my html it behaves like how it is mentioned in the original question on my post, even with the `!important` tag. I also tried applying the styles on the `element.style` in chrome. Still no go and I have the underline. Its going to be hard to convince otherwise so I am going to abandon this for now.

Comment: @BinodGurung: I am sorry! You did understand me correctly. But I can assure that it is for some reason not working in my code even though it seems to work in your snippet. I would have deleted this whole question if SO allowed me to. Sorry for wasting your times.

Comment: @Yathi in your code, does the link have a class applied?  Check out this answer from the question you linked:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/1823378/2185093