# Element underlined because of parent anchor

Tags: css

I stumbled over the following today:

```css
 a { text-decoration: underline; }
 h1{ text-decoration:none;}
```

```html
<a href="#"><h1>Title</h1></a>
```

This results in an underlined title element.

The rule for the block element does not apply. I realise that I have to style the anchor element for the desired effect. My question is: why?

What is the rule in the spec that describes this behaviour?

Comment: When you put a small cardboard box with no bottom, into a larger box that does have a bottom, that bottom of the larger box does not magically dissolve in those places covered by the smaller box and leave a “hole” for stuff to fall through ... So why should this behave any different?

Comment: another fun stuff for you: `<span class="outer"><span class="inner">text</span></span>` + `.outer { color: green; text-decoration: underline; } .inner { color: black; }` gives green underline :) https://jsfiddle.net/58dsLvpq/

Comment: You should style your inner elements (guessing you have more than just the h1 shown) separately if you do not want them all to have an underline

Answer (score 0):

Just because your `h1` is inside the `a` tag that have the underline..so you will see it underlined, but in fact just his container have the underline. Your css is working correctly.

If you want to remove the underline for linked h1, just invert the dom order:

```css
a {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<h1><a href="#">My Linked H1</a></h1>

<h1>Not linked H1</h1>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But this is not true. If I add display:inline-block to the h1, there is no underline. From the spec: "Text decorations on inline boxes are drawn across the entire element, going across any descendant elements without paying any attention to their presence." More, see here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1823388/603569

Comment: You not mentioned inline-block in your question. So with the default display this is one of the possible solutions.

Comment: Maybe I was unclear. Your solution for sure works. My comment was pointed at your first sentence. (I am not looking for a solution, but for an explanation.)

Answer (score 0):

You can find [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp) some docs here for the anchor tag.

As you can read:

> **By default, links will appear as follows in all browsers**:
>
> - An unvisited link is underlined and blue
> - A visited link is underlined and purple
> - An active link is underlined and red

In your case you are setting the `h1` with `text-decoration:none` , but in fact, the `h1` has not `text-decoration` prop setted.

The `a` tag and childs are compiled by the browser with underline style by default.

[Here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp) some tips for styling anchor tags.