# How to underline only top-items in a nested list?

Tags: css, html, html-lists, nested-lists

Consider the following code:

```
<ol class=top>
  <li>Top item

    <ol>
      <li>Sub</li>
      <li>list</li>
      <li>item.</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
```

And css:

```
.top > li {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.top ol li {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fLvns1z0/1/

I want only the "Top item" be underlined, but instead whole text is underlined. Even `!important` doesn't help.
Any ideas how to make it work and keep the code as simple as possible?

Comment: @Dimple, I tried - doesn't work.

Comment: Wow... This is crazy. Yeah... `:(`

Comment: This seems illogical. I'd love to know the reason if somebody has the specifics.

Comment: @Turnip **Looks like it's really not possible:**

* [Problem with text-decoration in cascaded `<li>`](http://p2p.wrox.com/css-cascading-style-sheets/23540-problem-text-decoration-cascaded-li.html)
* https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823341

Comment: I take back my previous comment. It does make sense when use a different example: http://jsfiddle.net/3rror404/ntLgkmap/1/

Comment: @Turnip for the last one it's logical, as the span is inline and will get the style of underline (this is a known behavior) make it inline-block and it will change

Comment: Yes, you are correct. @TemaniAfif

Comment: @Turnip check the second example of my answer, inline-block will cancel the effect

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to add an extra `span` or any other element to achieve the result as said by others, you can use css `:first-line` sudo class, check the working example below:

```css
.top > li:first-line {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<ol class="top">
  <li>Top item
    <ol>
      <li>Sub</li>
      <li>list</li>
      <li>item.</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it's because of the behaviour of `<li>` tag. If possible, please add a `<span>` and it should be fine:

```css
.top span {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<ol class=top>
  <li><span>Top item</span>
    <ol>
      <li>Sub</li>
      <li>list</li>
      <li>item.</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Also, when you add a `<span>` tag, you are clearly giving a separation. Plus the real reason is I am unable to fix the other way. Sorry about that. `:(`

Comment: Haha that's exactly what I have come to just a minute before :) My workaround is even simpler - I use `<u>` instead of `<span>`. However it makes the code dirtier and doesn't look absolutely accurate because the `1.` is still not underlined. If there won't be better answers I will mark this as a solution.

Comment: @Stalinko **Looks like it's really not possible:**

* [Problem with text-decoration in cascaded `<li>`](http://p2p.wrox.com/css-cascading-style-sheets/23540-problem-text-decoration-cascaded-li.html)
* https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823341

Comment: @Stalinko No `<u>`, as it's deprecated. `:(`

Comment: w3c says it was deprecated in html4 but then redefined in html5: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_u.asp Also it is properly supported in all the browsers.

Comment: @Stalinko w3schools (the poor tutorial site) is *not* the same as the World Wide Web Consortium. The difference is quite important. If you need a reference, better to avoid w3schools, use something more trustworthy like MDN instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can redefine `text-decoration` with the same color as background:

```css
.top > li {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.top ol li{
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<ol class=top>
  <li>Top item
    <ol>
      <li>Sub</li>
      <li>list</li>
      <li>item.</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Or make some changes to the behavior of elements:

```css
.top > li {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.top ol{
  display:inline-block;
  width:100%;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<ol class=top>
  <li>Top item
    <ol>
      <li>Sub</li>
      <li>list</li>
      <li>item.</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: That's a nice hack. I did try this, but it didn't work out for me. `:(`

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman I added another one, you can try it also

Comment: Woah... That works too. But problem is with the `margins`. Use `padding` and `border-box`, that will be awesome.

Comment: We both fixed. LoL.