# Remove textDecorationLine from nested text

Tags: react-native, text

I'm new to `React Native` and I tried to create a text with an inline text as follows:

```
<Text style={{textDecorationLine: 'line-through'}}>
    $75.00{'     '}
    <Text style={{textDecorationLine: 'none'}>$50</Text>
</Text>
```

The problem is that it renders

> <s>$75.00     $50.00</s>

and not

> <s>$75.00</s>     $50.00

I've seen that there's a [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17347691/4759619) in `html`, is there a similar solution for `React Native`?

- Note: I tried to make the strikethrough appear in a `code` section but this feature seems to not work anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your code in following way

```
<Text>
      <Text style={{textDecorationLine: 'line-through'}}>$75.00</Text> 
      <Text style={{textDecorationLine: 'none'}}>$50</Text>
</Text>
```